# why a return is representable as ^^M in tex?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

The texbook says that a return is representable as `^^M`, I was wondering why is that, and any help on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is by design that the representation of a character with `^^` the ASCII code differs by 64, in ASCII code `CR` (`return` has `xD` whereas `M` has `x4D` which means a difference of 64 then, so actually one has to subtract `64` from the `^^` value to get the 'real'  character. -- this is part of the two-level input processing (as it is called in TeX by Topic)